# How to use column from outer select inside subquery

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use the value of a column called `children_ids` inside a subquery:

```
SELECT hotels.id,
       hotels.hotel,
       hotels.country,
       hotels.corrected,
       hotels.children_type,
       hotels.children_ids as children_ids,
       (SELECT SUM(trx_input.count) FROM hotels LEFT JOIN trx_input ON hotels.trx_id = trx_input.id WHERE hotels.id IN (children_ids)) as count_children,
       trx_input.count
FROM hotels
LEFT JOIN trx_input ON hotels.trx_id = trx_input.id
WHERE hotels.country = 'DE' AND children_type != 2
ORDER BY hotels.hotel
LIMIT 1000
```

But `count_children` is always `NULL`. If I replace `children_ids` with some real values, it works:

```
SELECT hotels.id,
       hotels.hotel,
       hotels.country,
       hotels.corrected,
       hotels.children_type,
       hotels.children_ids as children_ids,
       (SELECT SUM(trx_input.count) FROM hotels LEFT JOIN trx_input ON hotels.trx_id = trx_input.id WHERE hotels.id IN (338666,338665,338456,338691)) as count_children,
       trx_input.count
FROM hotels
LEFT JOIN trx_input ON hotels.trx_id = trx_input.id
WHERE hotels.country = 'DE' AND children_type != 2
ORDER BY hotels.hotel
LIMIT 1000
```

Is there any way to use the value of an outer column inside a subquery?

Comment: Your bigger problem would appear to be storing multiple values in a single column.  You should fix your data structure to use a junction table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want using `find_in_set()`:

```
   (SELECT SUM(i.count)
    FROM hotels h2 JOIN
         trx_input i
         ON h2.trx_id = i.id
    WHERE find_in_set(h2.id, h.children_ids) > 0
   ) as count_children,
```

However, you should fix your data structure to use a proper junction table.  Storing lists of ids in a comma delimited column is not the right way to store data.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace In (children_ids) by In ( select children_ids from hotels hotls1 where hotels.id = hotels1.I'd)